# Ocelot placeholder for downstream host

Tags: c#, gateway, ocelot

I have an *API Gateway* running in `.NET Core 3.1` using `Ocelot`. Everything works fine as expected.

Now I'm  trying to substitute the downstream host during the middleware process.

Here's my **configuration.json**:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/product/getProduct",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": "44300"
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/getProduct"
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:62012/"
  }
}
```

I want to change the `Host` in the `DownstreamHostAndPorts` at runtime as by this time from grabbing the claims out of the `jwt` I will know the tenant the user belongs to therefore know where to route there request.

To be more clear, a request to the gateway comes in at http://localhost:62012/api/getProduct,

Then I get the tenant from the `jwt` in the request that made this call and then redirect the request to the relevant `api` like so

http://tenant1.com/api/product/getProduct
or
http://tenant2.com/api/product/getProduct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create custom middleware and inject it after `Authentication` middleware. The best extension point would be `PreAuthorisationMiddleware`. Assuming you have a service to resolve tenant uri by user claims, something like this:

```
public interface ITenantHostResolver
{
    Task<Uri> Resolve(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal);
}
```

In your `Startup` class inject the middleware that will override downstream settings:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{

    var conf = new OcelotPipelineConfiguration
    {
        PreAuthorizationMiddleware = async (httpContext, next) =>
        {
            if(!httpContext.Request.Path.Equals("/api/product/getProduct"))
            {
                await next.Invoke();

                return;
            }

            var claimsPrincipal = httpContext.User;

            var tenantHostResolver = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITenantHostResolver>();

            var tenantHostAndPort = await tenantHostResolver.Resolve(claimsPrincipal);

            var downstreamRequest = httpContext.Items.DownstreamRequest();

            downstreamRequest.Host = tenantHostAndPort.Host;

            downstreamRequest.Port = tenantHostAndPort.Port;

            downstreamRequest.Scheme = tenantHostAndPort.Scheme;

            await next.Invoke();
        }
    };

    app.UseCustomOcelot(conf).Wait();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if the transformation of the downstreamRequest has worked because I always get the message that my call did not succeed, but the request Uri printed in the log is the one that should be transformed.

Comment: I went through the Ocelot code and this can never work. There is a call "UseLoadBalancingMiddleware" which happens after any of your custom middleware you can provide for Ocelot and it resets the changes made to port and host.